# Additional attributes in N-N mongoid (Like in pivot table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a has_many_and_belongs_to relationship between central and coordinators. 
So my mongo documents are represented as below:

```
central = {
    _id: 1,
    title: 'First Name',
    coordinators: [
        BSON[1],
        BSON[2],
        BSON[3]
    ]
}

coordinators = [
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: 'Me',
        centrals: [BSON[1], BSON[2]]
    },
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: 'Mateus'
        centrals: [BSON[1]]
    },
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: 'Gomes'
        centrals: [BSON[1]]
    },
]
```

---

If I do this:

```
@central = Central.find(1)
@coordinator = @central.coordinators.find(1)

@coordinator.can_edit = false
```

It will apply to the coordinators document resulting in this:

```
coordinator = {
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Me',
    centrals: [BSON[1], BSON[2]],
    can_edit: false
}
```

But what I really want to do is apply this can_edit attribute in the relationship, like in pivot table in RDBMS:

```
central = {
    _id: 1,
    titulo: 'First Name',
    coordinators: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: 'Me',
            can_edit: false
        },
        BSON[2],
        BSON[3]
    ]
}
```

Only for the central with id 1 I want to aply the can_edit to false.

I have to keep the relation between a Central and Coordinator, but in some situation, I want to have an additional information about that relation, like if I would not allow a coordinator to edit some data only in central with id 1.

How can I do this using mongoid?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was create another relation N-N:

Add on **central.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :blocked_coordenadors,
                             class_name: "Central",
                             inverse_of: :blocked_centrals
```

And in **coordinator.rb**:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :blocked_centrals,
                             class_name: "Central",
                             inverse_of: :blocked_coordenadors
```

And to check I do this:

```
central.blocked_coordenadors.include? coordinator
```